# width and height of UIImage greater than width and height of iPhone screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working with `UIImagePicker`. I tried to see the value of CGRect of imagePickerControl `(x,y,width,height)`

and when i took an image from it, and tried to see the dimensions of the image.

here's what i get..

for `UIImagePickerController`

```
CGRect  origin=(x=0.00000000000000000000000069882427, y=0.0000000097393906)
size=(width=0.00000000000000000000000069916742, height=0.0000000000000061414852)
```

***these values change everytime i snap an image..

and for snapped image, when i am printing size on console using

```
NSLog(@"image width %f", imageToprocess.size.width);
    NSLog(@"image height %f", imageToprocess.size.height);
```

the size shown is

```
UsingTesseractOCR[544:60b] image width 2448.000000
2013-12-17 16:40:56.897 UsingTesseractOCR[544:60b] image height 3264.000000
```

why is there difference between size of the camera and image taken from it, and why are the values in case of imagePicker so long??

Comment: How do you get the first rectangle?

Comment: CGRect f = imagePickerController.view.bounds;

Comment: it depends on camera quality,real environment,color combination and so many factors

Comment: may i know the reason why you want the image size

Comment: actually, i need to crop a rectangular part of the image (right in the middle). But before that, i need to make an overlay for the imagePickerController accordingly.

Comment: The values are long because you're printing using `%f`. Try `%.2f` to make your life easier.